# fstab doens't read mode value

Tags: debian, permissions, raspberry-pi, fstab, tmpfs

[Following this guide:](https://hallard.me/raspberry-pi-read-only/)

I set my `/etc/fstab` file in this way:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults             0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults,ro          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime,ro  0       1
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   nosuid,nodev         0       0
tmpfs           /var/log        tmpfs   nosuid,nodev         0       0
tmpfs           /var/tmp        tmpfs   nosuid,nodev         0       0
```

It works, but I have a problem with `/tmp` which has the following permissions:

```
stat -c "%a %n" /tmp
755 /tmp
```

As far as I know the default should be 1777, and I need this settings because I want to write some files there as normal user.

I tried to set the mode value in fstab:

```
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   nosuid,nodev,mode=1777   0       0
```

with no effects.
Of course `chmod 1777 /tmp` works fine but only until a reboot.

I'm running Debian Jessie on RPi3.
What is the right way to set permissions on a tmpfs?

Comment: Do you have an initramfs, or startup script that might be mounting this before the script which mounts everything in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Did you try to `chmod` `/tmp` when it's not mounted?  To easily do it, just change `fstab` to use a temporary location, reboot, `chmod 1777 /tmp`, change `fstab` back, and reboot.  I'm not sure it'll work but it might.

Comment: Didn't the tidbits in `man tmpfs` work?

Comment: The fstab line with `mode=1777` is correct. Did you reboot after changing it? `fstab` is only read at boot time (or when you call `mount` on an entry with `noauto`), changing it doesn't affect already-mounted filesystems.

Comment: @JuliePelletier that won't work. The "parent" directory has its own access rights, which get replaced once you mount anything on it. I usually do `chmod 000` for dirs where appl filesystems get mounted, to prevent accidental writes into unmounted dir.

Comment: @Gilles yes, I rebooted every time.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're suggesting

Comment: @Patrick it's a good point, but I don't know how to exhaustively search for such a script. I started from a standard Debian Jessie anyway. Would you explain a bit more how to find any script which would mounts /tmp before fstab?